# Is Adobe Dreamweaver able to speed up markup development process for ASP.NET developers

Tags: asp.net, dreamweaver

I understand that this question may be subjective, this is why I need an answer from an ASP.NET dev who has actually tried using Dreamweaver in conjunction with VS2010 ASP.NET MVC development.

While working on a web site development project, I spend 60% of the time fine-tuning the markup and css, 30% of time writing JS code and only 10% goes to C# logic coding. I am looking for the way to reduce the markup-mingling time to finish the projects more quickly. Is Adobe Dreamweaver able to help me, an ASP.NET MVC developer, to implement markups provided by designers more quickly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a big Yes and No and I'll try to explain because it's kind of up to how you use it.

1. **The Design view**

If you approach the whole implementation visually, from Design View, like Adobe thinks you're supposed to do it, it's a big conspiracy. You'll find yourself spending more time traveling miles across the screen with your mouse. Keyboard coding -> always faster, but not for newbies.

2. **Live View / Split View**

If you plan on using the built-in "Live view" or "Split view", it's slower than going with Alt+Tab / Ctrl+R. And there's no trick to solve cross-browser inconsistencies

3. **What really speeds thinks up**

The regular code completion, syntax highlighter, automatic tag closing (like when typing `</`), the xHTML templates, not using hacks on top of other hacks, not using conditional styles, ignoring everyone else in the room.

4. **What can you do to speed up front-end dev in general**

Besides outsourcing, it helps to know HTML & CSS good, and your experience and technique. If you put a div, then switch to CSS then back to some more divs, then back to some other CSS this takes longer than writing header + footer html code, then moving onto styling the divs, the menus, etc.

On top of everything, slicing images still takes time. And if you want to be able to rapidly change things in your layout in the future, or make sub-layouts based on a template, it's naturally going to take more time. And add to that, the cross-browser compatibility testing. If you have a boss and he tells you "let's support IE6" you might want to consider a career in a different company.

P.S.: Is this another [hunting topic](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/06/can-stack-exchange-capitalize-on-hot-trends/)? :)

Comment: Thanks. I will not spend time learning Dreamweaver then, since I don't see any valuable advantages. Also, this isn't a hunting topic. Was researching some CSS stuff, and some person at the forum, after he got a suggestion, said he is going to fire up DW and give a suggestion a try. This got me thinking maybe all the CSS is done via Dreamweaver these day =)